# Asking old or obscure TV and movie questions

Tags: discussion, support, scope, questions

I am not American, so I was brought up with a lot of TV shows and movies that most people on this forum would not have heard of. So my question is: can such questions have any point?

For instance there were Australian TV shows in the 80's that I watched such as *A Country Practice* or *Sons and Daughters* (not to be confused with the US show of the same name).

I also have some VERY obscure movie knowledge that very few people would know; I went to some movie sites where they were filming and spoke to directors etc. But I don't see what use that is in a question if nobody else knows the movie.

I'd also like to ask questions about really old movies and actors/actresses. Humphrey Bogart era and movies like *The Maltese Falcon*. I'm not a movie watcher of current blockbusters; I prefer to go back in time a lot.

Any thoughts/responses?

Comment: We need *more* questions about the "older" movies....we're not all millennials....some of us have snow on the roof and aches in our backs.

Comment: As other said go ahead. I have seen a lot of obscure film and TV show question here which I never heard before.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Practically, there might not be too many people who have seen some obscure Armenian TV show from the 1930s...but noone in their right mind would tell you to just "not bother" asking your questions. ;-)

You never know who could contribute to the site and who might have something interesting to answer to your questions. I'd **advise you not to just "give up" beforehand**, thinking noone will be able to answer your question. That's what leads to this ultimately becoming reality.

Generally, **we welcome questions on all kinds of films and TV-shows and we also have quite an international community**. Granted, the frontpage might sometimes look like we only do *Marvel* or *Game of Thrones*, but rest assured that we don't. ;-) **There's also many questions about "film classics"**, to which Bogart and *The Maltese Falcon* indutibaly count. And if you have some interesting questions on that, awesome!

But it is admittedly one of the smaller sites, so don't get too anxious when you don't get an answer on the first day or when you don't get the 30 upvotes the 57th Thanos question would get. The asynchronicity of this site is an advantage, though, and I've gotten excellent answers after *years* of inactivity on some of my questions.

I personally sometimes ask questions on lesser known things I watched, albeit knowing there might not be an answer for quite some time. But...I'm not in a hurry either. I don't ask questions because I need my problem solved right now. I do it because I like writing about interesting films and because I think it makes the site better for it.

Comment: Btw if you see a lot of typos it's because I am using a new kind of mouse; the last one was too small and bust my hand. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

No fancy answer comes to mind, but basically: **go ahead**, as long as they're on-topic, narrow enough, clear, they're a fit. **They might get lower views, sure, but they're a fit** - and what do you know, you might trigger some memories in other users or spark others' curiosity.

You don't have enough rep yet to create tags for those questions, but you can ask for other users to do it with a comment.

Answer (score 3):

That's nothing to worry about. Not having majority doesn't mean you should pack up and leave. You said you are not an American, neither am I. and I think lot of people aren't.

Hollywood being major player is the probable reason that most of the questions are about that. But with rare knowledge like you said you have, you'd be a valuable member to the community. Ask the questions that you have in mind, people here won't disappoint you, but will try to provide you an answer as best they can, or they'll at least try to point you in right direction. You can help out people who seeks guidance on un-popular or not very famous titles, which will get less reaction here.

I myself like old movies, it brings back some memories, nostalgia! and there are vast number of *great* movies/tv shows out there. people are never going to abandon the classics. As Paulie_D says, we should get more questions about them classics more.

If you have a doubt or in need for any help, you can always ask from a moderator and/or other users. Everyone will be happy to help, this is a very friendly community. Welcome to Movies and TV SE!