# I am interested in classic TV and Radio -- I think classic TV (like 1940s-1960s) are okay, but what of radio?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I currently have a specific question about an old and extremely obscure radio show -- is Movies the place where it can be asked? Is there a better stackexchange (I find one for amateur (Ham) radio but this is not about Ham radio)? Would a new stackexchange devoted to classic TV and radio be something to try to start?

Comment: The part about classic TV has been asked before: [Asking old or obscure TV and Movie Questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4519/46980)

Comment: well, maybe i will ask the radio question and see what happens.

Comment: @releseabe I can tell you quickly radio is out. (It has possibly been asked on meta already, too, but it's quite clearly off-topic.)

Comment: As to a new site, it would have to be about radio only (since "classic" TV is about as on-topic as non-classic TV here), but we're probably not able to tell you how much support there would be for such a site beyond proposing it and seeing what happens.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: why would a radio drama be out?

Comment: @releseabe Because...uh...it's...like...not a movie or TV-show.

Comment: In any case, though, identification is off-topic anyway.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: seeking info about an old show, when it ran, what were some plots, who was in it, sure seem on-topic. anyway, one could argue that TV and movies should not be a single stackexchange but i think they belong together -- i can think of no better place for old radio drama than here unless its own, lonely stackexchange.

Comment: @releseabe To be honest, I have a hard time getting *what exactly* your question is asking anyway from its text. It *seems* to be asking for the name of that show, though (if not, your tags are wrong anyway).

Comment: Interesting though it would be to have a site for radio questions, radio shows tend not to be syndicated worldwide and so would fall under a *too localized* close reason.  However, radio shows are on-topic at SF&F - of course science fiction shows only.